# Kendo-Vue-Grid Way to not lose sort when datasource is refreshed?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-vue

I have a kendo-vue-grid like so:

```
    <kendo-grid v-bind:data-source="loggedInUsers"
                v-bind:sortable-mode="'multiple'"
                v-bind:sortable-allow-unsort="false"
                v-bind:sortable-show-indexes="true"
                v-bind:height="250">
        <kendo-grid-column field="username" title="Agent Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="count" title="Count">
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

`loggedInUsers` which is used as datasource in above contains elements like:
`{ username: 'test', count: 1 }` .

My problem is that this `loggedInUsers` array gets updated every five seconds and when it gets updated, all the sorting that is done on columns gets lost. Is there a way to preserve this sort settings?

Answer (score 0):

In case with Kendo Vue Wrapper Grid you will have to save the the state in a similar way as it is done [in this example](https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie) - instead of cookie you could use your state management system.

You could also check the new [Native Kendo Vue Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-native/sorting/) that is built specially for Vue cases from the ground and has no dependency to jQuery. It has a **sort** prop that can be saved and used in the state management system.

Comment: I am using the Kendo Vue Wrapper and that doesn't seem to have this option, nor the `onSortChange` event.